# Is it possible to Make HTTP/2 requests with Apache HTTPClient 4.2.5?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x, http2, alpn, tls1.3

I'm trying to make an HTTP/2 request with apache client. Is it possible with the below versions?

migrating the versions in my web application cost me heavy code changes. Is there any workaround to support HTTP/2 with TLSv1.3 in httpclient-4.2.5.jar?

> **Apache libs i'm using:**
>   
> httpclient-4.2.5.jar
>   
> httpcore-4.2.4.jar
>   
> httpmime-4.2.5.jar

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like HTTP 2 is supported only from version 5. [Apache Http Client Status](https://hc.apache.org/status.html)

> The main focus of the 5.0 series is providing full-featured support for HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 and ensuring full compliance with RFC 7230, RFC 7231, RFC 7540 and RFC 7541.

According to the [Apache Http Client News](https://hc.apache.org/news.html) it is still not a stable release of version 5.

However, from Java 11, there is a new [Http Client introduced](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) with HTTP 2 support.

> It supports HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2, both synchronous and asynchronous programming models